# Remove install icon on iOS 7

Tags: ios, icons, ios7, dashboard

Do you know what really grind my gears?

I distribute some beta apps from a ftp server. The apps are signed with a wildcard profile. While installing these apps, appears an icon with the progress. This install icon should be gone as soon the app is ready. But on iOS 7 these icons stays. It ends with the app icon and the buggy install icon. I can delete the app, but not the install icon.

The "X" button in missing too.

How to get rid of this icon?

[image]

Comment: may the down voter explain why?

Comment: You get any solution? I am also facing same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I will update this question as soon as I found a solution.

Comment: I am facing same problem ,when installing the apps.So far i can delete it.but not install perfectly.

Comment: my way to delete the installing icons steps like these 
1) delete the apps that you install
2) then click OTA to install again
3)during the installing faster delete it

Comment: did the issue occur because you have an iOS7 device or because you built with the iOS7 SDK?

Comment: It occurred because it was an iOS7 device.

Comment: ahh thanks. Are you able to clarify what/where app.xml is or the manifest.plist file mentioned in another solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was having the same problem with OTA apps I was making.  Before I solved the problem, the only way to remove the "Installing..." icon was to do a factory reset on the device (unless its jailbroken).

I changed the bundle identifier string in the .plist file for my OTA app to match the "id" of the app.xml.  This made it so there was no longer two separate icons while it downloaded the app and nothing leftover on my dashboard after the install.

Comment: It is absolutely the mismatching bundle identifiers that causes this problem in iOS 7.0.2 (6 doesn't seem to have this behavior). You can confirm the issue in the device log. The other way of removing the "Installing..." or "Waiting..." icon is to build a version of the app with the bundle ID in the "bad" plist file and install that one OTA.

Comment: @LocDog could you explain what you mean by "id" of the app.xml?

Comment: We ran into this very same issue. Thanks for bringing it forward and for pointing out the way to address it.

Comment: @LocDog - I am also interested in what you mean by 'app.xml'. Where is this configuration? In the app? In the OTA solution?

Comment: I think its not actually the app.xml file but rather the manifest.plist LocDog is talking about. Look at Arkady solution below.

Answer (score 11):

A workaround I did to get rid of that icon is:

- Download that app again
- While the text under that icon is saying **"Loading"** (do not wait until the text changes to "Installing") you should be able to delete the icon

Answer (score 5):

If you can't confirm what the bad identifier of that app is. You could link your device to XCode. Than find the `Console` of your device in `Organizer`. Search log like these:

```
Nov 21 18:52:33 YourNamemato-iPhone lsd[1116] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Currently 2 installed placeholders: (

"LSApplicationProxy: com.example.YourBadApp (Placeholder)"
)
```

Good luck, `com.example.YourBadApp` is the bad identifier. You could make a validate fake app using this identifier. Reinstall the app from OTA correctly. Finally, delete it.

Answer (score 3):

Worked great. Just to comment - when you upload your app to the webserver you have yourappname.ipa and yourappname.plist 
The plist section must be the same as your app id in info.plist

```
    <dict>
      <key>bundle-identifier</key>
      <string>same_as_your_app</string>
```

Comment: YES, I was also facing same problem. Just correct budleIdentifier in .plist file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the bundle-identifier property in your Over-the-Air install manifest.plist matches the CFBundleIdentifer in the app's Info.plist. I also made sure that the title property in the manifest.plist matched the CFBundleName in the Info.plist as well.

Comment: where is the OTA manifest.plist file? I don't see one in my project

Comment: You need to create one if you're planning to distribute your app over the air. Here's a good tutorial on how to do it: http://digitalpublishing.tumblr.com/post/29479304378/installing-your-developer-app-over-the-air-without